# TypeORM. Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call \"qb.set(...)\" method to specify updated values

Tags: mysql, typescript, express, relational-database, typeorm

I'm using a MySQL DB, TypeORM and ExpressJS.

I have 2 entities: User and Client. There's one-to-one relationship between them. Client has foreign key.

I get following error when I save a client:

> Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated values

User Entity:

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  role: string

  @Column()
  email: string

  @Column()
  password: string

  @Column({ default: '' })
  avatar: string

  @Column()
  firstName: string

  @Column()
  lastName: string

  @Column()
  fullName: string

  @Column({ default: '' })
  phone: string

  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  description: string

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  age: number

  @OneToOne(_type => Freelancer, freelancer => freelancer.user, { nullable: true })
  freelancer: Freelancer

  @OneToOne(_type => Client, client => client.user, { nullable: true })
  client: Client
}
```

Client Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Client extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  companyName: string

  @ManyToOne(_type => Position, position => position.clients)
  position: Position

  @OneToOne(_type => ClientReview, clientReview => clientReview.client, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  review: ClientReview

  @OneToMany(_type => Project, project => project.client, { nullable: true })
  projects: Project[]

  @OneToOne(_type => User, user => user.client)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User
}
```

Overview of code in auth.service, where I save `client`:

```
const user = userRepository.create({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      role,
      description,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
      phone
    })

      const clientRepository = getRepository(Client)
      const positionRepository = getRepository(Position)

      const positionEntity = await positionRepository.findOne({ id: position.id })

      const client = clientRepository.create({
        companyName,
        position: positionEntity,
        user
      })

      await userRepository.save(user)
      await clientRepository.save(client)
```

When I remove column `user` from entity Client, Client and User are saved, but separately, without a relation between them. But I want a relation between them.

What did I do wrong?

How should I fix it?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I forgot to add `@JoinColumn` at a `@OneToOne` relation.

Answer (score 0):

HI you have to make the relationship using

```
client.user = user
```

before saving your client & user

Answer (score 0):

From the [Github issues](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3869), it seems like a number of different things can cause this generic error message.

In my case, I found out that the problem was that the "other" object that I was trying to save onto "this" object (in your example, "other" = `user`) wasn't a full object yet (I might not be using the right terminology). In my case, I had to fully retrieve `user` before attaching it to `client` and then saving client.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the undefined DTO I was trying to save.

```
this.clientRepository.update(+id, updateClientDto);
```

and the updateClientDto was undefined so I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that I had a column that I mark as not able to update inside of one of my relations. So when I tried to update the main entity the cascade effects triggered the error.

```
@Column({ update: false })
```

What I did was to remove that column from the update payload because the value was not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had { cascade: false }, but the entity I was passing was malformed without "id".

After I sent the id, it solved the issue.